# Defining Gestures inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following table view and every single cell has 3 views.

If I tap on the blueView, the cell will be selected.
If I tap on the redView, I will call an alert.
And if I tap on the green one, the cell would resize.

[image]

I'm having trouble figuring how to make the UITapGestureRecognizer work inside each one of these views. Here's how I'm setting up my cell.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was adding my views directly into the UITableViewCell. Adding them into the contentView did the trick.